# Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range in for loop

Tags: ios, swift

In my `sampllat` and `sampllong` array contains 40 `double` values and `reflat` `long`  array contains 9 `double` values

```
 var counterR = 0
 var counterS = 0

  for testing in (0..<sampLat.count)
    {
        let coordinates = CLLocation(latitude:sampLat[counterS], longitude:sampLong[counterS])

        for testing1 in (0...refLat.count).reversed()
        {

            let coordinates2 = CLLocation(latitude:refLat[counterR], longitude:refLong[counterR])

            let distanceInMeters = coordinates.distance(from: coordinates2)

            print("distance found",distanceInMeters)

            print("Counter Reference", counterR)

            if(  distanceInMeters <= 50 )
            {
                print("crossed check point", counterR)
            }else
            {
                print("out of range")
            }
            counterR = counterR + 1
            print("---------------------------------------")
        }

            print("Counter Sample", counterS)
            counterS = counterS + 1
            print("******************************************")
  }
```

Comment: counterR is never reset

Comment: `(0...refLat.count)` is wrong. should be `(0..<refLat.count)`. Btw better to iterate your array indices `for index in refLat.indices.reversed() {` And you should use the index. Forget about using a counter

Comment: and this is exactly why I advise people to never write `0..<arr.count`. Too easy to accidentally write `0...arr.count` instead. Use `arr.indices`, wherever possible.

Comment: @Alexander And It is worth mentioning that not every collection necessarily starts from 0 index and/or goes all the way through count-1. `ArraySlice` also conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the inner loop, in particular in:

```
for testing1 in (0...refLat.count).reversed()
```

That will iterate in one more value than you have in `refLat`, what you would want is:

```
for testing1 in (0..<refLat.count).reversed()
```

But in general, you can make the code simple by using directly the indexes generated by the for loops, so instead of managing your own `counterR` and `counterS`, let `for` loop do it for you:

```
// counterS will be generated and managed by the for loop
for counterS in (0..<sampLat.count) {

    let coordinates = CLLocation(latitude:sampLat[counterS], longitude:sampLong[counterS])

    // same for counterR
    for counterR in (0..<refLat.count).reversed()
    {

        let coordinates2 = CLLocation(latitude:refLat[counterR], longitude:refLong[counterR])

        let distanceInMeters = coordinates.distance(from: coordinates2)

        // I will use string interpolation
        print("distance found - \(distanceInMeters)")

        print("Counter Reference - \(counterR)")

        if distanceInMeters <= 50 {
            print("crossed check point for - \(counterR)")
        } else {
            print("out of range")
        }
        print("---------------------------------------")
    }

    print("Counter Sample \(testing)")
    print("******************************************")
```

}